# Postman throws bad request while sending JSON as request parameter in Rest Api

Tags: java, rest, postman

Sending `json` as request parameter in `Rest` api from Postman throws `Bad Request Exception.`

I encountered this while testing a legacy system. Sending json in a request param is not a good idea unless you cannot avoid it like in my case.

So, what is the correct way of sending json as request param from Postman?

Comment: We need a minimal example to help you. What does your controller look like and expect and what do you input in the postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the json param and select `Encode URI Component` before sending the request.

[image]